# Firebase IDs - can I extract the date/time generated?

Tags: firebase

I need to date/timestamp various transactions, and can add that explicityly into the data structure.

Firebase creates an ID like IuId2Du7p9rJoT-BARu using some algorithm.

Is there a way I can decode the date/time from the firebase-created ID and avoid storing a separate date/timestamp?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no.

I've asked the same question previously, because my engineer instincts tell me I can never duplicate data. The conclusion that I came to after I thought this through to the logical end, is that even in a SQL database there exists tons of duplication. It's simply hidden under the covers (as indices, temporary tables, and memory caches). This is a part of large and active data.

So drop the timestamp in the data and go have lunch; save yourself some energy :)

Alternately, skip the timestamp entirely. You know that the records are stored by timestamp already, assuming you haven't provided your own priority, so you should be good to go.